# Access in-memory unzipped file with codecs.open()

Tags: python, memory, codec, zip

I'm trying to open in-memory unzipped files with `codecs.open()`. I've figured out how to unzip a file in memory, but I don't know how to create a file object and open it with `codecs`. I've experimented with different `ZipFile` properties, but no luck.

So, here how I opened the zip in memory:

```
import zipfile, io

f = 'somezipfile.zip'
memory_object = io.BytesIO(f.read()) 
zip_in_memory = zipfile.ZipFile(memory_object)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `codecs.open()` to access data in memory -- it is meant for loading files from disk.  You can extract the file contents from your zipfile obbject using its `extract()` method and decode the resulting string using `decode()`.  If you insist on using the `codecs` module, you can also get a file-like object by `zip_in_memory.open(...)` and wrapping the returned object with [`codecs.EncodedFile`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.EncodedFile).

Comment: But I want to, for speed. I'm rewriting the code so that files are accessed in memory, and not in a temp file.

Comment: @marw: You want what?  The point of my answer is that you don't need to use `codecs.open()` and that you can't even use it if your file is already in memory.